# Change timedelta64[ns[ to string

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have both Date and Time which is being imported from MySQL. The Date column is object type while Time is timedelta64[ns] type. I wanted to combine them and put it as an index column on the DataFrame, so that I could put it as x-axis labels in the graphs. I tried a lot of ways but nothing seems to work out for me. Is there any way to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first have to cast the object type to a datetime object:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then we can just add the time difference to the date by using:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Date'] + df['Time']
```